# Filtering words out of Doc object

Tags: python, filter, spacy, doc

What is the fastest way to filter Doc object by using token attr.
(Because spacy does not allow to delete tokens)

On normal string sentences split to words I use Pipe module and do something like this :

```
 filtered = words | size(3,15) | is_word | isnt_stop | lwcase | lemma
```

using spacy-pipelines for every item is unfeasible.

The only I see is to convert tokens to list-of-words and then recreate the Doc obj at the end out of the filtered.

BTW I want to keep the original POS,NER...etc .. so this complicates things

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in this case is define a component in spaCy that sets a [custom attribute](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines/#custom-components-attributes) for each Token which is either `None` (you don't want to keep it) or your normalized value (the lowercase lemma or whatever). When you want your cleaned tokens, you can just iterate over the Docs and only take those where the value is set.

You mention using spaCy for everything is infeasible but you don't mention why. If you want the POS and NER values then you'll need to run the original spaCy pipelines anyway though, so this seems like the easiest way.

Also note the kind of preprocessing you're doing is generally not useful for modern NLP, for more details see [the spaCy preprocessing FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10243).